# How can I clone a Boot Camp Windows 7 partition to a USB drive and boot a Mac from it?

Tags: windows, macos, usb-flash-drive, boot-camp

I have a small Windows 7 Boot Camp partition on a MacBook (computer A).

I have to give this computer away, but want to keep the Windows installation and the software and data on it.

I have a USB stick with enough space to contain the Windows partition.

If I used `dd` to copy the Windows 7 installation onto the USB stick, would it be bootable on a different Intel Mac (computer B)?

Is there a better way to achieve this with minimal disruption?

Corollary: I've read Windows won't even boot from a USB stick. Is this the case? 
What are the conditions for a Windows partition to be bootable on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can install windows onto a USB device using VMware or similar, then edit the registry to make the USB drivers load on boot. I got it working using the instructions at this website which took me a long time to find.

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/204022-vista-installed-usb-hard-drive.html

Answer (score 1):

Your asking several questions here, I'll try to answer them all.

To backup a bootable partition, try [Paragons Backup & Recovery](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/brh/features.html) for a BootCamp Windows backup. (according to [fortuny](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Fortuny) [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3212516?start=0&tstart=0)

Wether or not you can boot Windows from a USB stick is determined by the kind of motherboard your using.  Check your manual if you're unsure.  (Installing windows 7 from a USB stick although possible, is rather difficult.  This may be what you're referring to, but I'm not sure).

[This](http://www.intowindows.com/bootable-usb/) site contains instructions for making a bootable USB stick (in Windows).

Comment: Macs can boot OS X from a USB key no problem. I want to boot a fully working copy of Windows 7 from a USB key. Preferably I want it to be the copy i already have from the computer that will be going away.

Comment: @jackslash depending on your motherboard, this should be easy.  Just go to the *Boot Menu* and select the USB drive.

Comment: Booting from a USB stick isn't my issue. The startup manager on a Mac will show all bootable devices. The trick will be making a bootable Windows 7 USB stick. Im not sure that Paragons software can achieve that